# WPF Application App.xaml Not Finding View Models

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, app.xaml

I'm creating a multi-page WPF application, which uses the MVVM model to navigate between pages. All views, models, and viewmodels are created and named accordingly, none of which *should* be overlapping.

Upon building, App.xaml throws these errors:

> XDG0008   The name "AscentView" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Valorant_Lineup_Library.MVVM.View"

> XLS0414    The type 'view:AscentView' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

> The tag 'AscentView' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Valorant_Lineup_Library.MVVM.View'. Line 15 Position 18.

Each class appears properly in those namespaces, and I can't determine how this could be happening. Below I'll leave the snippets of my code relating to these issues.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Valorant_Lineup_Library.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Valorant_Lineup_Library.MVVM.ViewModel"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Valorant_Lineup_Library"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="600" Width="920"
        WindowStyle="None"
        Background="Transparent"
        AllowsTransparency="True">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    
    <Border Background="Black">
        <Grid>
            
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ContentControl Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="10"
                            Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>

        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

**App.xaml** (Edit: removed trailing `assembly=` from `ViewModel` namespace. Was leftover from previous attempts to resolve issue.)

```
<Application x:Class="Valorant_Lineup_Library.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Valorant_Lineup_Library"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Valorant_Lineup_Library.MVVM.ViewModel"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Valorant_Lineup_Library.MVVM.View"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:AscentViewModel}">
                <view:AscentView/>
            </DataTemplate>
            
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**MVVM/View/AscentView.xaml Namespaces (created as UserControl)**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Valorant_Lineup_Library.MVVM.View.HomeView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Valorant_Lineup_Library.MVVM.View"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

</UserControl>
```

I apologize if this is a lot to look at but I greatly appreciate any help! Also, I was loosely following this video as I was creating the application if this is any help:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzP8mw7JUzI&t=848s

Comment: In MainWindow.xaml, your `xmlns` for the `viewModel` namespace ends in `assembly=`.  Remove that trailing bit and try again.  So make it look like this:  `xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Valorant_Lineup_Library.MVVM.ViewModel"`

Comment: Note that I am assuming your MainWindow.xaml lives in the same assembly as your view and view-model

Comment: @Joe Just went in and fixed that, my problem unfortunately wasn't as simple as that. That trail was leftover from previous attempts to reference the assembly within the namespace. I edited the post so that wouldn't be mistaken for the issue any further.

Comment: And do they all (the `MainWindow`, `View` and `ViewModel`) all live in the same assembly?  If not, there's your answer.    If so, can you show us at least the first few lines of each class in code-behind, (including the namespace they live in)?

Comment: @Joe Sorry if I misunderstand anything, but ```View``` and ```ViewModel``` are subfolders for the ```MVVM``` folder of my project. Each respectively contained AscentView.xaml and AscentViewModel.xaml. AscentView.xaml.cs starts off with ```namespace Valorant_Lineup_Library.MVVM.View```. Could the subfolders be causing an issue with where App.xaml is trying to find the files?

Comment: By "same assembly" I mean ***are they defined by the same C# project***?  If they were defined in *separate* projects, then you would need to add project references from the project holding `MainWindow` to the project holding `View` and `ViewModel` (which you can do in Solution Explorer)  You would also need to change your `xmlns` lines to properly include that `assembly=` part, only this time with the proper assembly name at the end.

Comment: The subfolder names should generally correspond to namespace names. So your view-model should live in a folder named  `Valorant_Lineup_Library\MVVM\ViewModel`  And in the .CS file that defines that View-Model, the namespace declaration should be literally `namespace Valorant_Lineup_Library.MVVM.ViewModel{`.  Finally make sure the classes are all listed as `public` when they are declared.

Comment: I just realized; I'm assuming you're building this project on .NET 5 or .NET 6.  Are you?  Or is it .NET Framework ?

Comment: @Joe I'm currently targeting .NET Framework 4.8. Also yes, everything resides within the same project/assembly.

Comment: Well then check the other things I mentioned;  Make sure the view-and view-model class files are part of the project and are getting built at build-time and are being compiled into the proper namespaces that you  used in your XAML and that they're declared as public.  My best guess is that you have the namespaces wrong but a guess is all it can be because you still have not edited your question to show us the code that declares these classes.

Comment: There is no `AscentView` indeed. The control is `HomeView` - at least from your sparingly posted code. You probably renamed the class without refactoring tools and forgot to update the XAML code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to comment as I don't have enough reputation for it, and I'm not sure if this will help ,but I had this problem often when I started with View Models and what fixed it for me was rebuilding the Solution and making sure the view models are public, and then the error would go away.